# Collection View UINib register in custom UIView crash with Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I've a custom `UIView` that I'm displaying inside a `ScrollView`. On my `UIView` I've added a `CollectionView` and created a custom `.xib` for it's cell.

In my `UIView` I've `@IBOutlet weak var productShowcaseCollectionView: UICollectionView!` and then:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initCollectionView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initCollectionView()
}

private func initCollectionView() {

    self.productShowcaseCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PrizeShowcaseCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) //crashes on this line
    productShowcaseCollectionView.dataSource = self
    productShowcaseCollectionView.delegate = self

}
```

When I run it, the crash occurs at `self.productShowcaseCollectionView.register` that reads:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value: file

Comment: have you provided the proper reuseIdentifier?

Comment: check in debug mode what property is nil, if UINib can't be created, check your custom cell class name

Comment: Where is is `file` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this register within your `viewDidLoad` function (or any time after that).

`productShowcaseCollectionView` (an `IBOutlet` property) doesn't exist until that view is loaded.

Comment: But `productShowcaseCollectionView` `IBOutlet` is in `UIView` so how can I initialize it in `ViewController`?

Comment: call `initCollectionView` from your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method instead of the view's `init` method.

Answer (score -1):

Just call `productShowcaseCollectionView.register` in the `viewDidLoad` function of the `ViewController` your `CollectionView` is contained in. 
Your IBOutlet will be nil until that time.

Your `CollectionView` `delegate` and `dataSource` are usually implemented by the containing `ViewController` and should referenced in the `viewDidLoad` function the same as described for the registering.
That way it become more reusable.
For some cases it is fine to use the `delegate` and `dataSource` inside the object itself, but I am not sure what exactly your use case is here.

I would not recomend calling the register function inside the `CollectionView` anyway because that way it can't be reused with other cells.